# PHP using Propel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I am having an issue when I try to post the Join Date on my web page:

> Fatal error: Class 'getJoinDate' not found in ********

```
$newDate = getJoinDate::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $dateFromDB);

$posts = PostQuery::create()->findPk(1);
echo "<p>", "ID:".$posts->getUserID().", ".$posts->getContent().", ".$posts->getJoinDate()." </p>";'
```

Please let me know what I must do to display the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this code:

```
echo "<p>", "ID:".$posts->getUserID().", ".$posts->getContent().", ".$posts->getJoinDate()." </p>";'
```

I'm not sure what your commas were supposed to be, but I guess not actual commas and so you have commas where stops should be: `echo "<p>", <--`
And an apostrophe at the end of the line: `</p>";'<--`

You should grab a decent IDE that will show errors like this immediately, saves a lot of time. And read your error log as it tells you such errors.

Using double quotes variable names will be expanded, try this:

```
echo "<p>ID: {$posts->getUserID()} {$posts->getContent()} {$posts->getJoinDate()}</p>";
```

Or this way:

```
echo '<p>ID: ' . $posts->getUserID() . ' ' . $posts->getContent() . ' ' . $posts->getJoinDate() . '</p>';
```

Comment: What IDE do you recommend?

Comment: Depends on what you do. For large projects I recommend an IDE (I use PHPStorm) for smaller work then just a decent code editor with syntax highlighting will be fine.